# Rails Abstract Class Child: Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, abstract-class

I am getting an error when seeding my database table "apollo_wh_rules" with rails that is as follows:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `simple_guards' for #<Apollo::WhRule:0x0055ffed9928f0>
```

I recently changed a model I have called "Apollo::WhRule" to inherit from a new abstract class, which itself inherits from another abstract class.

**My Model**

```
class Apollo::WhRule < Marty::SqlRule
```

**SqlRule Abstract Class**

```
class Marty::SqlRule < Marty::BaseRule
  self.abstract_class = true

  before_validation(on: [:create, :update]) do
    self.expressions ||= {}
  end
```

**BaseRule Abstract Class**

```
class Marty::BaseRule < Marty::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  before_validation(on: [:create, :update]) do
    self.simple_guards   ||= {}
    self.computed_guards ||= {}
    self.grids           ||= {}
    self.results         ||= {}
  end
```

So how do I stop this error from occurring? I tried to make a method in my Apollo::WhRule class called simple_guards but that did not work?

What am I missing within how this setup is working and what is the best way to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on with just this line:

```
self.simple_guards   ||= {}
```

It's easier to understand exactly what's happening if you look at this slightly longer but functionally equivalent code:

```
self.simple_guards = self.simple_guards || {}
```

This will be evaluated such that the right side of the `=` will be "resolved" first. So the first thing that will happen is that `self.simple_guards` will be evaluated, which is leading to the error that you posted. You're on the right track to add a `simple_guards` method to your `Apollo::WhRule` class. Adding that method should allow the right hand side of the line to completely resolve.

I'd bet that after you added the `simple_guards` method that the error changed just ever so slightly and was then complaining about a missing `simple_guards=` method (now with an equal sign at the end of the method name). This is because after the right hand side has been resolved to a value, the left hand side is evaluated to see where to store the result. You can get past the error by defining a `simple_guards=` method.

If you wanted to store the value in a temporary variable and then return that value the two methods together might look something like this:

```
def simple_guards=(simple_guards)
  @simple_guards = simple_guards
end

def simple_guards
  return @simple_guards
end
```

This is a common enough pattern that there are helper methods you can use instead:

```
attr_reader :simple_guards
attr_writer :simple_guards
```

And if you're going to use both of those helpers, you can simplify them into a single line:

```
attr_accessor :simple_guards
```